# puppet define two variables in require, but one variable not work

Tags: variables, puppet, require

I defined some variables in my defined type `remote_file`.

When I instantiate this type in `class cdnlog::base`, if I commented the line with `require_dir`, I get some error message in puppet client:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid relationship: File[cdnlog-release] { require => , }, because , doesn't seem to be in the correct format. Resource references should be formatted as: Classname['title'] or Modulename::Classname['title'] (take careful note of the capitalization).
>
> Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
>
> Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

My manifest:

```
define remote_file($remote_location=undef, $path=undef, $mode='0644', $require_dir=undef){
  exec{"retrieve_${title}":
    command => "/usr/bin/wget -q ${remote_location} -O ${path}",
    creates => $path,
  }
  $require_exec="Exec[retrieve_${title}]"
  if $require_dir {
    $require_file="File[$require_dir]"
  }
  elsif $require_dir == undef {
    $require_file=","
  }
  file{$title:
    path    => $path,
    mode    => $mode,
    require => [$require_exec, $require_file],
  }
}
class cdnlog::base{
  tag 'cdnlog'

  file {'/etc':
    ensure       => directory,
    recurse      => true,
  }
  file {'/etc/rc.d/init.d':
    ensure       => directory,
    recurse      => true,
  }
  file {'/etc/cdnlog.d':
    ensure       => directory,
    recurse      => true,
  }

###########################################
###########################################
###########################################
  remote_file {'cdnlog-release':
    path                  => '/etc/cdnlog.d/cdnlog-release',
    remote_location       => "${collectd_server}/tarball/cdnlog-release",
    require_dir           => '/etc/cdnlog.d',
  }
  remote_file {'cdnlog.conf':
    path                 => '/etc/cdnlog.conf',
    remote_location      => "${collectd_server}/tarball/cdnlog.conf",
    require_dir           => '/etc',

  }
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your efective resource after variable substitution is:

```
  file{'cdnlog-release':
    path    => '/etc/cdnlog.d/cdnlog-release',
    mode    => '0644',
    require => [Exec['retrieve_cdnlog-release], ","],
  }
```

That is not valid.
You should try using

```
  $require_exec=Exec["retrieve_${title}"]
  if $require_dir {
    $requirearray=[$require_exec ,File["$require_dir"]]
  }
  elsif $require_dir == undef {
    $requirearray=$require_exec
  }
  file{$title:
    path    => $path,
    mode    => $mode,
    require => $requirearray,
  }
```

Quotes should be placed inside brackets, too

Comment: that's correct answer。@Raul Andres thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Adding a refactor to Raul's great answer, for posterity.

```
file { $title:
    path    => $path,
    mode    => $mode,
}
if $require_dir {
    File[$title] { require => [ $require_exec , File["$require_dir"] ]
}
elsif $require_dir == undef {
    File[$title] { require => $require_exec }
}
```

It saves you from juggling too many unnecessary variables.